# Integral $I=\int_{0}^{+∞}\frac{{e^{-tx} }}{x}(\cos ax-\cos bx)\,\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

We know that $$\int{e^{ax} }\cos bx\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left(a\cos \left(bx\right)+b\sin \left(bx\right)\right)+C$$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.
I'm interested in solving the following related improper integral,
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{e^{-tx} }}{x}(\cos ax-\cos bx)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
with $t\gt 0$ and $a,\,b,\,t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Where should I begin?

Comment: Your question is not clear,could you please tell us what are $a,b$ and $t$ and what have you tried?

Comment: @ArpitKansal.I'm sorry .I edited

Comment: your first integral doesn't necessarily converge :/

Comment: @tired.How is solve  integral 2?

Comment: your impudency makes it easier to vote for closing...

Comment: Here is a [possible source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Integrals_involving_exponential_and_trigonometric_functions) for the OP's first integral.

Comment: This is the Laplace transform of $\frac{\cos{ax}-\cos{bx}}{x}$. You can easily find $F(s)$ with the help of Laplace tables and then replace $s$ by $t$

Comment: @polfosol Am I going crazy, or should the restriction on the parameter $t$ actually be $t\geq 0$ instead of $t\gt 0$?

Comment: @teadawg1337 what difference does it make? Don't go crazy about these minor things ;)

Answer (score 4):

The usual Frullani-integral-type technique works in this case:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} \frac{\cos(ax) - \cos(bx)}{x} \, dx
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} \bigg( \int_{a}^{b} \sin(xu) \, du \bigg) \, dx \\
&= \int_{a}^{b} \bigg( \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} \sin(xu) \, dx \bigg) \, du \\
&= \int_{a}^{b} \frac{u}{u^2 + t^2} \, du \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\log\left( \frac{b^2+t^2}{a^2+t^2} \right).
\end{align*}

This technique can be also thought as the Laplace-transform technique in disguise.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint-** Take the Laplace transform of $\cos ax$
$$\mathcal{L}\{\cos ax\}=\frac s{s^2+a^2}$$
And also note that if $\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}=F(s)$ then:
$$\mathcal{L}\{\frac {f(x)}x\}=\int_s^\infty F(\sigma)d\sigma$$

Comment: Remove that $u(x)$ from the first equation @polfosol. ;)

Comment: @Babak I usually ignore that $u(x)$. But I have learnt a thing or two that when you are dealing with mathematicians, you have to be careful about everything and use precise definitions and notations. Otherwise you end up being hammered over and over!

Answer (score 1):

Let's first assume $I$ as this (note that $I$ can be taken as a function of $t$)
$$I(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\mathrm{e}^{-tx} }}{x}(\cos ax-\cos bx)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
So, differentiating with respect to $t$ would give you 
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}I(t)&=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-tx}(\cos ax-\cos bx)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-tx}\cos ax\,\mathrm{d}x +\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-tx}\cos bx\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
But you know the closed form solution for the latter integrals (note that as $x\to\infty$ the result simplifies), hence
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}I(t)&=-\frac{t}{t^2+a^2}+\frac{t}{t^2+b^2}\\
\end{align}
By integrating you'll get
$$I(t)=\frac12 \log\left(\frac{t^2+b^2}{t^2+a^2}\right)+C$$
To determine $C$ you should note that $I(t)$ has to be zero for the special case where $a=b$. This implies $C=0$. Finally
$$I(t)=\frac12 \log\left(\frac{t^2+b^2}{t^2+a^2}\right)$$